# Joda Time - Converting Calendar object to LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

I have a method `getCalendarFromClass` that returns me an object of `Calendar`.

And I am converting it into `LocalDate` of Joda Time API using `fromCalendarFields` method.

```
LocalDate.fromCalendarFields(a.getCalendarFromClass());
```

But how can specify the `TimeZone` when performing this conversion as I didn't found it in javadoc.

The javadoc for `fromCalendarFields` method mentions :

*Each field is queried from the Calendar and assigned to the LocalDate. This is useful if you have been using the Calendar as a local date, ignoring the zone.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Calendar` has a time zone, and that will be used (by the `Calendar`) when Joda Time requests the different field values. Joda Time just uses `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)` etc.

The returned `LocalDate` doesn't have a time zone, conceptually.

Comment: the db from where I am receiving the calendar has time zone as GMT but I first I want to convert it to EST and then process it

Comment: @Abu: Do you mean you want to take the stored *instant* and convert it to EST (by which I assume you mean EDT/EST depending on the date)? If so, just set the time zone on the `Calendar` to the right time zone before converting to `LocalDate`.

Answer (score 11):

1) Get the timezone:

```
TimeZone tz = calendar.getTimeZone();
```

2) Create a Joda DateTime from Calendar:

```
DateTimeZone jodaTz = DateTimeZone.forID(tz.getID());
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), jodaTz);
```

3) Get a LocalDate

```
LocalDate localDate = dateTime.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 1):

LocalDate doesn't look like the class you want. From the doc:

> LocalDate is an immutable datetime class representing a date *without*
>   a time zone.

(my emphasis)